# Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in GenericHeader.php line 54. Magento2.3

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am using magento 2.3 on ubuntu 18 and everything was working properly before reinstallation.

I was installing ubuntu again so I have saved my project to be able to move it later to new operational system after installation is done. Magento application is working but now I am getting **this error:**

> [php7:error] [pid 4358] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in
>   /vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/Header/GenericHeader.php on line
>   54

When I go to logout or after placing order on checkout the blank screen appears and in error log this line is shown.

I have tried to increase memory limit to 5000M but it doesnt matter how much memory limit I increase it will show again. Tried to use phpinfo() to check if memory limit is increased and it is but error still appears.

Comment: You have an infinite loop somewhere that utilises GenericHeader.

Comment: If you have an infinite loop, it won't matter how much you increase the memory limit.

Comment: Yes but how can I check it. As I said that projects was working properly before being moved to another location and now it's not working. At least it is working if not placed order or being signed out

Answer (score 1):

Answer to my question:

Magento project with that problem above that I mentioned is because that project is copied to usb flash driver because ubuntu is being reinstalled and after new fresh ubuntu installation I have added that project back to same location but it didnt worked. Needed to install magento application again from remote repo.